# jQuery AJAX requests are being sent without custom HTTP headers in Cordova app for iOS 9

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, cordova, http-headers

In a mobile app I'm building with Cordova using jQuery $.ajax for requests with custom HTTP headers to a back-end, on iPhone 6 (iOS 9.2) devices the custom headers are not being sent to the back-end. On Android and iPhone 4 (iOS 7.3) devices the headers are being sent perfectly. The back-end has CORS configured to accept all origins, all methods and all headers.

I use the following code to send requests:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://mybackend.example.com/api/resource",
  data: myData,
  beforeSend: function(request) {
    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + loginToken);
    request.setRequestHeader("X-My-Custom-Header", myHeader);
  },
  dataType: "json"
}).success(function(data, code, xhr) {
  // Do something on success
}).error(function(qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  // Do something on error
});
```

There are no preflight requests. Requests succeed, but it happens on iOS 9.2 devices the custom header X-My-Custom-Header is just omitted.

I tried to use *headers* instead of *beforeSend*, but no luck.

Comment: are you using the WKWebView plugin?

Comment: No, I don't use it

Comment: Oh, sorry, I saw once an user with header problems when using WKWebView plugin.

Comment: Hi Mislav, did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: Hi Joao, unfortunately I haven't. It seems it was an quite obscure bug nobody (or at least too few people) had bumped into it. I've never got an answer, I've never resolved it. :(